# Skip operand in condition if column doesn't exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next part of condition:

(COALESCE(some_day, now()) at time zone 'Some/TZ')::date - interval '1 day' + interval '1 day' * day_number

what I need is to skip `- interval '1 day'` if `some_day` is null. How I can do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that piece of logic in the `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(some_day - interval '1 day' ,
         now()) at time zone 'Some/TZ'
        )::date + interval '1 day' * day_number
```